# Fetch data after login

Tags: reactjs

I have a login component:

```
  const login = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const {data} = await loginUserRes({variables: {
      ...formData,
    }});
    if (data) {
      currentUserVar({
        ...data.loginUser,
        isLoggedIn: true,
      });
    }
  };
```

Which allows user to send some data to the server, if the credentials are correct a JWT is stored in a cookie for authentication.

I'm wondering what he best approach is to fetching data after a log in, on the dashboard I have a list of movies that the user has added. Should I use a react effect to react to the `currentUserVar` changing and then do request for the movies? Or perhaps I could add all the dashboard data to the return object of the apollo server, that way the data is present on login.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should react to your authorization data, But this info always considered as global state that you will need it in the whole app. so It is recommended to save your `currentUserVar` in a react `context` or whatever you are using to handle global state, Even if the app was small and you don't have global state then you can left it to your root component so you can reach this state in all your components.

**Here how I handle auth in reactjs**, I don't know if it is the better approach but I'm sure it is a very good solution:

1. Create a wrapper component named `AuthRoute` that checks if the user is logedin or
   not.
2. Wrap all components that require user auth with `AuthRoute`
3. If we have user data then render wrapped component.
4. If there is no user data then redirect to `Login` component

```js
const AuthRoute = ({component, children, ...rest}) => {
  const Component = component;
  const {globalState} = useContext(GlobalContext);

  // Return Component if user is authed, else redirect it to login page
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={() =>
        !!globalState.currentUser ? ( // if current user is exsits then its login user
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={ROUTES_PATH.SIGN_IN.index}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

Then any component can fetch the needed data in it's mount effect `useEffect(() => { fetchData() }, [])`. and this is an indirect react to userData.

Note: if you are not using routing in your app, you still can apply this solution by converting `AuathRoute` component to HOC.